# numpy array division turns all elements to zeros

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to divide each element in each row of a matrix by its index, I've created a matching row and filled it from 1 to 1000, however when I do the following:

```
d = data[0]/np.arange(1,1001)

data[0] = data[0] / np.arange(1,1001)
```

printing `d` gives the right caculation:

```
[1.         0.5        0.33333333 0.25       0.2        0.33333333
 0.28571429 0.25       0.22222222 0.2        0.18181818 0.16666667
 0.23076923 0.21428571 0.2        0.25       0.29411765 0.33333333
 0.31578947 0.35       0.38095238 0.40909091 0.39130435 0.375
 0.4        0.42307692 0.40740741 0.42857143 0.4137931  0.43333333
]
```

while printing `data[0]` prints a row of zeros:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
```

Comment: What is stored in `data`?

Comment: Can you post how `data[0]` looks like?

Comment: data stores integers, and data[0] looks like this (the dimensions fit):                                                          ''' [0.25       0.25       0.25       0.         0.05       0.08333333
 0.10714286 0.         0.02777778 0.05       0.06818182 0.08333333
 0.09615385 0.03571429 0.01666667 0.         0.01470588 0.02777778
 0.03947368 0.05       0.05952381 0.06818182 0.0326087  0.04166667
 0.05       0.05769231 0.02777778 0.03571429 0.04310345 0.05
 0.05645161 0.03125    0.03787879 0.04411765 0.05       0.05555556 '''

Comment: Does data stores integer or floats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said data[0] is an array of int, so the result of the division is again cast to int, hence you get all 0.

While d is not an array of ints, so the result of the division is cast to float.

```
data = np.ones((2,1000)).astype(np.int8)
d = data[0]/np.arange(1,1001)
data[0] = data[0] / np.arange(1,1001)
```

This sample example will lead the same result:

- data[0] will be an array of zeros (except the element at index 0 that will be a 1)
- while d will be an array of the float results of the division.